# no puedo concatenar esto en kotlin: println(str1 == str2 "$s") //error

Tags: kotlin

Quiero imprimir mi variable s con el  true en el mismo `print`

```
println(str1 == str2 "$s") //error
```

Pero no se como hacerlo, coloco la pregunta porque quizá sea algo fácil y puedan ayudarme

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val str1 = "Hello, World!"
    val str2 = "Hello," + " World!"
    val s = "Hello, world!\n"
    println("$s")
    println(str1 == str2)   // print true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres es publicar una evaluación en el String, esto se logra con los ${} donde puedes colocar cualquier expresión que se evaluará en el momento de la publicación.

```
println("${str1 == str2}" + " $s")
```

En los {} puedes colocar expresiones mas complejas si necesitas, por ejemplo: Si quisiera comparar la primera letra con la ultima del otro string.

```
println("${str1.first()==str2.last()}" + " $s")
```